# How to setup a Ubuntu mail server that accepts any emails from *@*.ca and forwards them to an external email address?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, sendmail

I'm trying to setup a small Ubuntu server that would accept basically any emails and would forward all of them to the email address of my choice.
I did some research and I think it would be possible to do with `postfix`, but I'm really not familiar with it.

Can someone provide me with a detailed explanation on how I would go about doing this ? I'm starting from scratch from a fresh Ubuntu server, I have tried adding this to the *main.cf* of `postfix` but it's not working.

```
luser_relay = redirect@myemailaddress.com 
local_recipient_maps =
```

The end goal is that I would just create a MX record pointing to my server for all my domains that I use and emails would start flowing (temporarily). I understand the security risks and spam issue.

Thanks for the help

PS: **I'm open to any other ways of doing this**, if anyone knows any applications or easiest way to do that, it would work for me.

Comment: Give me a few and I should have an answer for you.

Comment: I have a working version for *@<a_list_of_domains>.ca. If you really, really want *@*.ca I can do that, but it is slightly more work. Do you really need to accept mail for the TLD "ca?" Even a list of hundreds of domains could be easily imported...

Comment: Yeah that could work *@*.ca it would be a great start. Yes I really need to accept mail for the TLD "ca" and importing domains is currently not a solution for now unfortunately, I will look at your answer and let you know ! thanks for your feedback and time !

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not accept mail for the entire "ca" TLD. This is because I found out that wildcard domains in the VirtUser table require patching an m4 file.

This answer does provide a way to take a list of .ca domains and rewrite the recipient to an external address.

## Install Sendmail, start it.

```
apt-get install sendmail
service sendmail start
```

## Making sendmail listing on all adapters

By default sendmail will listen on localhost (127.0.0.1). We need to edit sendmail.mc to make it listen on all IPs.

```
vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

Change:

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
```

... To ...

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=0.0.0.0')dnl
```

... then build the sendmail.cf file:

```
m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

... then restart sendmail:

```
service sendmail restart
```

Now we need to confirm that sendmail is listening on all adapters. Use netstat, you should get something like this:

```
netstat -tpln
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6104/sendmail: MTA:
...
```

## Making sendmail RELAY mail for the "ca" TLD:

We need to edit the "access" file to tell sendmail to accept mail for the "ca" TLD.

```
vim /etc/mail/access
```

Add this anywhere around other "RELAY" statements. This causes sendmail to accept any mail with a '*.ca' recipient address.

```
To:ca                   RELAY
```

Save and exit...

Then use makemap to make the access.db hash map file:

```
makemap hash /etc/mail/access < /etc/mail/access
```

Restart sendmail:

```
service sendmail restart
```

## Testing the RELAY statement with telnet from external server:

From an external server use telnet to manually test a "*.ca" recipient:

```
telnet your_mail.server 25
```

Here are the commands I typed in the telnet session:

```
helo testing.com
mail from: ttucker@ttucker.net
rcpt to: ttucker@derp.ca
quit
```

Here is a sample of what the output should look like:

```
root@zim:~# telnet dib.ttucker.net 25
Trying 52.43.174.20...
Connected to dib.ttucker.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3; Mon, 5 Jun 2017 04:36:55 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: [23.227.163.72](FORGED)-billing.bizzhost.com [23.227.163.72] (may be forged)
helo testing.com
250 localhost Hello billing.bizzhost.com [23.227.163.72] (may be forged), pleased to meet you
mail from: ttucker@ttucker.net
250 2.1.0 ttucker@ttucker.net... Sender ok
rcpt to: ttucker@derp.ca
250 2.1.5 ttucker@derp.ca... Recipient ok
quit
221 2.0.0 localhost closing connection
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If you see this:

```
rcpt to: ttucker@derp.ca
550 5.7.1 ttucker@derp.ca... Relaying denied. IP name possibly forged [23.227.163.72]
```

... then something is not working ...

## Configured virtusertable and virtuser-domains

In order to rewrite the recipient of any incoming emails for our .ca domains we are using the virtusertable.

First we edit sendmail.mc again to enable some features:

```
vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

Find the line:

```
FEATURE(`access_db', , `skip')dnl`
```

... and add the following lines after it ...

```
FEATURE(`virtusertable')dnl
VIRTUSER_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/virtuser-domains')dnl
FEATURE(`virtuser_entire_domain')dnl
```

**Note: the FEATURE() syntax begins with a backtick and ends with a single quote**

... save and exit ...

Compile the config file:

```
m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

## Adding a domain to virtuser-domains file:

We need to tell sendmail what domains it should look at the virt user table for. Since sendmail does a best left hand match on the domain we can put just the TLD "ca" in here...

```
vim /etc/mail/virtuser-domains
```

... add the "ca" domain:

```
ca
```

... (yes, the file just contains "ca") ... save and exit

## Adding the rewrites to the virtusers table:

Next we need to tell sendmail what to rewrites to make. We add these to the virtusertable. As stated above, you will need to add each domain to this file either manually or with a script.

```
vim /etc/mail/virtusertable
```

... add your domains:

```
@derp.ca         someone@gmail.com
@another.ca      someone@gmail.com
@sendmail.ca     someone@gmail.com
```

... save and exit ...

Now we need to user makemap again:

```
makemap hash /etc/mail/virtusertable < /etc/mail/virtusertable
```

**Note: you should have a /etc/mail/virtusertable.db file now**

... restart sendmail:

```
service sendmail restart
```

## Testing the rewriting with sendmail -bv

You can use sendmail on the server to test to make sure the virtusertable rules are working as expected:

```
root@dib:/etc/mail# sendmail -bv ttucker@derp.ca
ttucker@derp.ca... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host gmail.com., user someone@gmail.com
```

## Testing an actual email:

On an external server run telnet again:

```
telnet your_email.server 25
```

... after the banner comes back, copy and past the following:

```
helo testing.com
mail from: ttucker@ttucker.net
rcpt to: ttucker@derp.ca
data
subject: This is a test
from: ttucker@ttucker.net
to: ttucker@derp.ca

Hello Self,

This is a test.

Regards,
.
quit
```

All together it should look like this:

```
root@zim:~# telnet dib.ttucker.net 25
Trying 52.43.174.20...
Connected to dib.ttucker.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 dib.ttucker.net ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3; Mon, 5 Jun 2017 06:28:46 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: [23.227.163.72](FORGED)-billing.bizzhost.com [23.227.163.72] (may be forged)
helo testing.com
mail from: ttucker@ttucker.net
rcpt to: ttucker@derp.ca
data
subject: This is a test
from: ttucker@ttucker.net
to: ttucker@derp.ca

Hello Self,

This is a test.

Regards,
.
quit250 dib.ttucker.net Hello billing.bizzhost.com [23.227.163.72] (may be forged), pleased to meet you
250 2.1.0 ttucker@ttucker.net... Sender ok
250 2.1.5 ttucker@derp.ca... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
250 2.1.0 ttucker@ttucker.net... Sender ok
250 2.1.5 ttucker@derp.ca... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
250 2.0.0 v556SkbP009313 Message accepted for delivery
250 2.1.0 ttucker@ttucker.net... Sender ok
250 2.1.5 ttucker@derp.ca... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself

221 2.0.0 dib.ttucker.net closing connection
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

## After thoughts:

You may also want to increase the log level of sendmail because the default log level isn't very verbose.

Add the following to sendmail.mc, do the compile and restart:

```
define(`confLOG_LEVEL', `14')dnl
```

## Google "grey listed" me pretty quickly... I think ...

So, my first email test went through and was placed into spam. Every test afterwards I am getting a 4xx (deferral) code from gmail servers. This makes sense as this looks like hella spammy stuff...

The mail did eventually go through, but it took a few minutes. Issuing 4xx codes is one way mail servers use to "rate limit" spamming looking servers.

You will likely want to set up whitelist rules on the receiving server because these emails as they will look spammy as hell.

## What this looks like in the sendmail logs:

Note, this is with log level "20" because that shows locked message and I was troubleshooting:

```
root@dib:/etc/mail# grep v556cKKt010016 /var/log/mail.log
Jun  5 06:38:20 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: Milter: no active filter
Jun  5 06:38:21 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: --- 220 dib.ttucker.net ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3; Mon, 5 Jun 2017 06:38:20 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: [23.227.163.72](FORGED)-billing.bizzhost.com [23.227.163.72] (may be forged)
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: <-- helo testing.com
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: --- 250 dib.ttucker.net Hello billing.bizzhost.com [23.227.163.72] (may be forged), pleased to meet you
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: <-- mail from: ttucker@ttucker.net
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: --- 250 2.1.0 ttucker@ttucker.net... Sender ok
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: <-- rcpt to: ttucker@derp.ca
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: --- 250 2.1.5 ttucker@derp.ca... Recipient ok
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: <-- data
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: --- 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: from=ttucker@ttucker.net, size=110, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201706050638.v556cKKt010016@dib.ttucker.net>, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=billing.bizzhost.com [23.227.163.72] (may be forged)
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10016]: v556cKKt010016: --- 250 2.0.0 v556cKKt010016 Message accepted for delivery
Jun  5 06:38:25 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: makeconnection (gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [IPv6:2607:f8b0:400e:c04:0:0:0:1a]) failed: Network is unreachable
Jun  5 06:40:25 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: makeconnection (gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.202.26]) failed: Connection timed out with gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Jun  5 06:40:26 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: makeconnection (alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [IPv6:2607:f8b0:4001:c1a:0:0:0:1b]) failed: Network is unreachable
Jun  5 06:42:26 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: makeconnection (alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.196.26]) failed: Connection timed out with alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Jun  5 06:42:26 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: makeconnection (alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [IPv6:2607:f8b0:4002:c03:0:0:0:1b]) failed: Network is unreachable
Jun  5 06:44:26 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: makeconnection (alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.219.27]) failed: Connection timed out with alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Jun  5 06:44:26 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: makeconnection (alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [IPv6:2607:f8b0:400d:c0c:0:0:0:1a]) failed: Network is unreachable
Jun  5 06:44:26 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: SMTP outgoing connect on ip-172-31-42-65.us-west-2.compute.intern
Jun  5 06:44:27 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: to=ttucker@derp.ca, delay=00:06:02, xdelay=00:06:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=120110, relay=alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.68.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1496645067 v28si8540518qth.285 - gsmtp)
Jun  5 06:44:27 dib sm-mta[10020]: v556cKKt010016: done; delay=00:06:02, ntries=1
```

Comment: Actuall;y, now that I am looking at the logs more... I wonder if I just had some network issues on the server I was running... eh...

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look at that when I have a minute and will let you know the outcome ! :)